# VTL adds whitespaces to string

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, openapi, velocity, vtl

I am using mapping template in AWS API Gateway methods Integration response.
I found that it adds unwanted whitespaces to the return string. I have read Velocity references and tried all trimming and replacing I could think of. However there still seems to be 3 whitespaces before text.
My actual code is more complicated but this is a short example of the problem.

```
#set ($test = "Foo bar")
##return that
$test.toString().trim()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably, the extra spaces come from elsewhere in the template.

First, you can try to add some extra characters to understand where the spaces come from:

```
<#set ($test = "Foo bar")>
@@##return that
<$test.toString().trim()>
```

and look where the spaces do fall.

Also, you can try to comment end lines to see if it changes something:

```
#set ($test = "Foo bar")##
##return that
$test.toString().trim()##
```

Comment: Thank you. I added comments to end of each line. Then I added "row numbers"  between each code line. This way I found what line was causing thso whitespaces. I have made "too readable" code with spaces within one If-else branch.